# windows 7 does not allow creation of more than 2 groups in an 8 core system

Tags: windows, winapi, multiprocessing

I have a intel r xeon r cpu w3565 system. I am running a 64 bit windows 7 on top of it.

with no group awareness the task manager shows 8 logical cores as needed(4 cores and 8 threads).

Now if I need 4 groups with 2 prcessors each I did this:

bcdedit/set groupsize 2  and restarted my machine. I could see 2 groups with 2 logical processors each.
I also ran a small test program :

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {   
    WORD numProcs = 0,i;    
    int sum=0;
    numProcs = GetActiveProcessorGroupCount();   

    for(i=0;i<numProcs;i++)
    {
         int procs;
         procs =GetActiveProcessorCount(i);         
         printf("\ngroup %d count :%d\n",i,procs);       
         sum += procs;   
    }   
    printf("numProcs: %d\n", sum);    char abc;    scanf("\n%c",&abc);   
    return 0; 
}
```

Which also gave core count as 4. earlier this gave it as 8(without group awareness on)

Now if I set group size to 4 I get 2 groups with 4 cores each. and my test program output is 8 this time.

I then set groupsize to 1 and this time I again got 2 groups with a single logical core in each core.

I am unable to understand why windows cannot expand the number of groups to 4 when actually the documentation says that it can go max uptil 4.

Any idea what I am missing here?

Comment: Please fix your code formatting.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I was not sure which shortcuts keys were needed!

Comment: Also, I use  task manager (which is group aware I think) to see the cores in the system

Answer (score 1):

I think you missed this portion of [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff564483%28v=VS.85%29.aspx):

> By default, a system that has 64 or fewer active logical processors has one processor group.  One must set the processor group size to forcibly configure such a system to have multiple processor groups.
>
> If a system is configured with a processor group size that is less than one-fourth of the total number of logical processors in the system, some of the logical processors are not used.

That is a contributing factor for why you only see 2 logical processors per group when you set the groupsize to 1.  That is less than 1/4 of the total number of logical processors that are available.  I would have expected 4 groups to be created, and even the example in [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff564483%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) says as much.

I don't know why you only see 4 logical processors when setting the groupsize to 2.

[The documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff564483%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) does state that processor groups affect the system's non-uniform memory access (NUMA) nodes, so maybe that is a factor in how many processors are assigned per group?  There must be other factors in play on your system that are limiting the number of processors per group.

Comment: Yes, That makes sense. Though I am not sure why I cannot get 4 groups with group size 1 and 4 groups with group size 2. Nevertheless, I missed this 1/4 of total clause. Thanks! appreciate it